# Constructing a model for formula in propositional logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Construct a model for fomula $F = \forall x \exists y(p(x,y) \land \lnot q(y,x)) \land \forall x \exists y \lnot p(x,y)$. 
 
 So if i want to construct a model i need my formula $F$ to be true in all valuations $F=_v1$. But i fail to see how can this formual be true. 
Let $A = \forall x \exists y(p(x,y) \land \lnot q(y,x)) $ and $B = \forall x \exists y \lnot p(x,y)$ This formula is in form $ A \land B$ so i need both $A = _v1$ and  $B = _v1$. But if i constct $p$ such that $\forall x \exists y( p(x,y))=_v0$ then when i negate it( since in $B$ i have $\lnot$) i get $B = _v1$ as needed. But then  $ A = ( \forall x \exists y p(x,y) \land \forall x \exists \lnot q(y,x))$. Since i have consturcted $p$ such that $\forall x \exists y( p(x,y))=_v0$ and i consturct $q$ such that  $ \forall x \exists \lnot q(y,x)=_v1 $, then i get $A = (0 \land 1 ) = 0$  i.e. $ F = A \land B = 0 \land 1 = 0$. Thus i cant construct a model for $F$. I could constuct a counter model if i let both $p$ and $q$ be rleation $\ge$. Am i missing here something or there is mistake in probelm.

Comment: I think that your problem is that you are "reasoning" in *propositional* logic (as the title of your question sugegsts), when it is a problem of *predicate* logic.

Comment: Following the answer below, we can "recycle" your attempt. Choose for $p(x,y)$ $x < y$; thus both $∀x∃yp(x,y)$, which is $∀x∃y(x < y)$, and $∀x∃y¬p(x,y)$, which is $∀x∃y(x \ge y)$, are *true* in $\mathbb N$. For $q$ we need something which is trivially *false*, like $(x \ne x \land y \ne y)$; thus, $∀x∃y¬q(y,x)$ will be $∀x∃y(x = x \lor y = y)$, which is trivially *true*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take $q$ to be never satisfied. Now for $p$ take a linear order on a set with no minimal or maximal element. So every $x$ will have a $y$ larger than it, and also a $y$ not larger than it.

Comment: I think your confusion might arise from using $x$ and $y$ for both $A$ and $B$. The values may be differnt. $A$ says for every element there is a larger one. $B$ says every element there is an element not larger than it. So in an ordering with no max or min element both can be true.